# How to create a list with 16 elements?

Tags: python

Please, help to create a list with 2 cycles "for":

```
for i in range(2):
        for j in range(3):
            list[????] = [0] # What should I write in place of the "????"
```

I need this result:

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
some_list = ...
...
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        some_list[i * m + j] = [0]
```

Comment: @quamrana This is a general solution to your problem, where n and m are variables. In your case, you should: 1. Use predefined values (put 2 and 3 in n,m places), 2. define n, m before loop execution.

Comment: Yes, I did that and I still get an error.

Comment: What kind of error?
Maybe your list is not initialized?
Maybe instead of accessing the exact elements, you should call .append()?

Comment: I get: `TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment`. What do you get?

Comment: You have to define your list first. You cant use ```list``` as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest is using

```
list=[[0]]*6
```

It will create a list with six times the entry [0]

Comment: Also, be aware that this gives you *one* list repeated 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `list` to start with and then append items to it:

```py
result = []
for i in range(2):
        for j in range(3):
            result.append([0])
```

But really its just 6 lists, so:

```py
i = 2
j = 3
for _ in range(i * j):
    result.append([0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have 2 for loop to achieve this.

Here is one on the multiple solution.

```
output = [] for i in range(6) :
    output.append([0])
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

liste=list()

for i in range(2):

```
for j in range(3):

    liste.append([0])
```

print(liste)